# Microsoft Service Fabric - fabric:/System/ImageStoreService not running

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I am trying to copy an app to the service fabric image store. 
I am not able to copy the application via VS or Powershell (probably because of the fabric:/System/ImageStoreService being in Error state). The operation times out when done using Visual Studio and when done using Powershell - it just stays stuck indefinitely.

I don't know how to approach services that are not running on the Service Fabric Cluster. I have other services failing on the cluster as well - this is a new test cluster created using the Azure portal yesterday (see attached screenshot).

---

Error event: SourceId='System.FM', Property='State'. Partition is below target replica or instance count.
ImageStoreService 3 3 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000003000
N/P InBuild _nodr_0 131636712421204228
(Showing 1 out of 1 replicas. Total available replicas: 0)

---

[image]

Comment: You should provide the error details that you get when you deploy your ap, this error message is very generic in service fabric to describe that the service could not reach the number of replicas expected.

Comment: @DiegoMendes The operation either keeps on waiting (on powershell) or times out (on Visual studio). I seem to have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Try deleting and recreating the cluster, make sure that you use at least VMSize D2 for creation. You can scale down your test cluster after the deployment succeeded.